# How to visible all items inside groupbox in c#

Tags: c#

I have a windows form which include some textbox and labels.In my program I set all of them unvisible and when I press button it makes all of the labels and textbox visible with the code below and it works perfect.

```
List<Label> lbls = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();

foreach (var lbl in lbls)
{
    if (lbl.Name.StartsWith("label"))
    {
        lbl.Visible = true;
    }
}
List<TextBox> txts = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();

foreach (var txt in txts)
{
    if (txt.Name.StartsWith("textBox"))
    {
        txt.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

But when I put all of my labels and textboxes into groupbox.My code doesn't work.How can I do this?

Note: My groupbox is also unvisible and when I press button.

```
groupBox1.visible =true;
```

This code works and groupbox panel seems, but the code of labels and textboxes doesn't work.

Comment: Because the groupbox has its own controls container property. When you do it from the form, it won't work, because it's not checking for any other containers.

Comment: "My groupbox is also unvisible and when I press button.

groupBox1.visible =true;"  -- that would make them visible, not invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are working with the immediate child of Form here

```
List<Label> lbls = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
```

Notice `this` that means your current form. so when you have controls outside in form it works,

But when you put them inside group box it won't be the immediate child anymore.

so use

```
List<Label> lbls = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
```

This will give you access to immediate children of the group box.

Comment: This works I will accept as an answer 4 min later :)

Comment: Take a look at my answer. It will provide a more robust way of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sure thing @ThePerplexedOne that your code provides a better approach, but my intention here was to make questioner understand why his code was not working instead of just giving him another approach, so I gave such answer. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off creating a recursive method of your own. Try implementing something like this:

```
    private void MakeControlsInvisible(Control container, params Type[] controlTypes)
    {
        foreach (Control control in container.Controls)
        {
            if (controlTypes.Contains(control.GetType()))
            {
                control.Visible = false;
            }
            if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                MakeControlsInvisible(control, controlTypes);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then using it on whatever container you wish:

```
MakeControlsInvisible(this, typeof(Label), typeof(TextBox)); // Will make all labels and textboxes inside the entire form invisible.
MakeControlsInvisible(groupBox1, typeof(Label), typeof(TextBox));// Will make all labels and textboxes inside groupBox1 invisible.
```